# Error After Renaming Package Name in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, package, rename

I bought a radio code for android studio, the problem I have is that when I change the name of the package the android module is eliminated

[screenshot about android module removal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Str.png)

My problem is that I am not an expert in programming issues, please I will be very grateful to you.
Thank you so much..

[catch on message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnF2W.png)

Comment: What steps you tried to rename package?

Comment: Please explain what you did and how you it and what steps were taken to solve it . Use code block for sharing stack trace

Comment: Just do with the rename refactor steps nothing more as they told me in the guide that I bought together with the code